# Cocos 2d , App working on my all devices but when submitting to apple store they send me black screen appearance just with background sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
2014-03-20 20:04:14.370 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.1
2014-03-20 20:04:14.372 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2014-03-20 20:04:14.401 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: OS version: 7.1 (0x07010000)
2014-03-20 20:04:14.402 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2014-03-20 20:04:14.402 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2014-03-20 20:04:14.403 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE-9.4.3
2014-03-20 20:04:14.403 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2014-03-20 20:04:14.404 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2014-03-20 20:04:14.404 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2014-03-20 20:04:14.405 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.405 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.405 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.406 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.406 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2014-03-20 20:04:14.407 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.407 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2014-03-20 20:04:14.408 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2014-03-20 20:04:14.410 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2014-03-20 20:04:14.411 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:fps_images.png in CCTextureCache
2014-03-20 20:04:14.411 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: Could not open file: fps_images.png
2014-03-20 20:04:14.412 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: Could not initialize CCAtlasNode. Invalid Texture
2014-03-20 20:04:14.413 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning HD file not found: Default-568h1@2x-hd.png
2014-03-20 20:04:14.481 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
2014-03-20 20:04:14.482 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2014-03-20 20:04:14.483 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: surface size: 640x1136
2014-03-20 20:04:16.481 Diving Merlin[3199:60b] cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning HD file not found: Splash-render-5_newfdsd-hd.png
```

Comment: is this the whole log ? , did they send crash report ?

Comment: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" <-- search for this, that's your problem right there.

Comment: no they didn't send any crash report, app is not crashing but not loading images but they said background sound in playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your app cannot find the images.

First make sure they are included in your build, by checking your build phase. [You can find it here](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com/images/Xcode_5_01.png)

Also file names are case sensitive. Make sure the file name you provide in your code is exactly the same as the file name being referenced by the app. This is something that the simulator forgives but the actual device doesn't.

Comment: THanks for your quick response, but every thing working fine on all my devices but when I am submitting this app to apple store, they just rejected by saying that we are getting black screen on iPhone5s with ios7.1 , but its working fine on my side, I have read some details of retina display issue with cocos2d v1.0.1 but i am unable to figure it out why its working fine on my devices

Comment: Delete your app from your device and run it on it again. You've probably have done something since your last build on the device that has resulted in your images not being included in your build. Your app will run because the images have stayed on your device since your last 'correct' build. If you delete the app from your device you can test your new build without any resources staying from previous builds. I suggest doing this before submitting to the app store just to make sure everything is included in your project.

Comment: I already did this many times on every device, but dont know what apple wants?

Answer (score 2):

cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil. Make sure you add all files as resources in your project and check Build Phases to see if there are set to be included in (Copy Bundle Resources).

Comment: THanks for your quick response, but every thing working fine on all my devices but when I am submitting this app to apple store, they just rejected by saying that we are getting black screen on iPhone5s with ios7.1 , but its working fine on my side, I have read some details of retina display issue with cocos2d v1.0.1 but i am unable to figure it out why its working fine on my devices

Answer (score 0):

Please provide @2x version of your images, let's say MyImage.png and MyImage@2x.png (for retina, scaled as needed). You can also check if device has retina support and adjust your code for the two cases: 1. device with retina support, 2. device without retina. You can check simple for iPhone if device supports retina. If you're on iPad version, check for -hd version of your images. To reproduce the bug Apple complains about, just test your app in iPhone simulator with **Retina display**. I think you'll get a black screen and you can continue to debug/inspect the cause. 
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] ) 
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
    }